# Limit and continuity

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

Hello I am a bit confused about this problem. It says, define a function f over the whole plane as $$f(x,y)=0$$ if $x=0$  and $$f(x,y)=0$$ if $y=0$  other wise defined  by $$f(x,y)=\frac{9x^3+y^3}{x^2+y^2}$$ now it asks, is f continuos over the whole plane? The answer it gives is not is is not but I am having trouble because I have tried approaching the origin by so many paths , and I consistently get a limit of zero. Even when I try using polar coordinates I still seem to get zero.

Does anyone have a guess and what I could be missing? Thanks

Comment: You need to try approaching a point other than the origin.  The value at, say, $(0, 1)$ is $0$, by the first rule.  What is the limit as you approach that point from the right?  From the left?

Comment: @BrianTung Thanks, so are you saying for example if I approach f(x,x) as x,y approach (1,1) , since I get a value of 5, this is a contradiction to the definition given?

Comment: Is that correct or no?

Comment: There's no discontinuity at $(1, 1)$. I'm suggesting that you look at the limit of the function for $(x, 1)$ as $x$ approaches $0$. If the limiting value doesn't equal the actual value, the function is discontinuous there.

Answer (score 0):

If it asks if the function is continuous over the whole plane, then it suffices to find a point at which it is not continuous. Maybe try the line $x = 1$?